# BigQuery API Quickstart Complete Source Code (Java) error

Tags: java, api, google-bigquery

I have beeen trying to run a Google Bigquery Query from my java eclipse, using the Complete Source Code that is presented in the BigQuery API Quickstart page:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart#authorizing

The code was changed to fit my project, all the client libraries are installed, and I keep getting this error message after running :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.(Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;Z)V
>       at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.(Bigquery.java:108)
>       at com.google.cloud.helix.samples.BigQuery.main(BigQuery.java:61)

the code Im using is this:

```
  package com.google.cloud.helix.samples;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Data;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.GetQueryResultsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryRequest;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * BigQuery sample code. Runs queries using client_secrets.json authentication.
 */
public class BigQuery {

  // Enter your Google Developer Project number or string id.
  private static final String PROJECT_ID = "61613421242";

  // Use a Google APIs Client standard client_secrets.json OAuth 2.0 parameters file.
  private static final String CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = "client_secrets.json";

  // Objects for handling HTTP transport and JSON formatting of API calls.
  private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {

    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\"+CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION;

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    InputStreamReader stReader= new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(),stReader);

    Credential credential = getCredentials(clientSecrets, new Scanner(System.in));

    Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
    String query = "SELECT TOP( title, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as revision_count "
        + "FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE wp_namespace = 0;";
    runQueryRpcAndPrint(bigquery, PROJECT_ID, query, System.out);
  }

  static Credential getCredentials(GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets, Scanner scanner)
      throws IOException {
    String authorizeUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(
        clientSecrets, clientSecrets.getInstalled().getRedirectUris().get(0),
        Collections.singleton(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY)).build();
    System.out.println(
        "Paste this URL into a web browser to authorize BigQuery Access:\n" + authorizeUrl);
    System.out.println("... and paste the code you received here: ");
    String authorizationCode = scanner.nextLine();

    // Exchange the auth code for an access token.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, Arrays.asList(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY))
        .build();
    GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode)
        .setRedirectUri(clientSecrets.getInstalled().getRedirectUris().get(0)).execute();
    return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
  }



  /**
   * Runs a synchronous BigQuery query and displays the result.
   *
   * @param bigquery An authorized BigQuery client
   * @param projectId The current project id
   * @param query A String containing a BigQuery SQL statement
   * @param out A PrintStream for output, normally System.out
   */
  static void runQueryRpcAndPrint(
      Bigquery bigquery, String projectId, String query, PrintStream out) throws IOException {
    QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest().setQuery(query);
    QueryResponse queryResponse = bigquery.jobs().query(projectId, queryRequest).execute();
    if (queryResponse.getJobComplete()) {
      printRows(queryResponse.getRows(), out);
      if (null == queryResponse.getPageToken()) {
        return;
      }
    }
    // This loop polls until results are present, then loops over result pages.
    String pageToken = null;
    while (true) {
      GetQueryResultsResponse queryResults = bigquery.jobs()
          .getQueryResults(projectId, queryResponse.getJobReference().getJobId())
          .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
      if (queryResults.getJobComplete()) {
        printRows(queryResults.getRows(), out);
        pageToken = queryResults.getPageToken();
        if (null == pageToken) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private static void printRows(List<TableRow> rows, PrintStream out) {
    if (rows != null) {
      for (TableRow row : rows) {
        for (TableCell cell : row.getF()) {
          // Data.isNull() is the recommended way to check for the 'null object' in TableCell.
          out.printf("%s, ", Data.isNull(cell.getV()) ? "null" : cell.getV().toString());
        }
        out.println();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**Can anybody tell what is the problem and how can I fix it?**

Comment: looks like there is a missing jar or an incompatible version of jar being used.

Comment: Can you tell me what jar is missing? Im having hard time to find it..

Comment: Check if you have the libraries listed here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart#requiredlibraries

Comment: Yes, I have everything.. maybe another cause of the problem you can think of?

Comment: Try to update your version of `google-api-client` from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list). What is the version your using now?

Comment: I have the latest version

Comment: what is the version no.?

Comment: 1.17.0  AND ALSO THE 1.18.0

Comment: just have one version of each jar file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have the exact same versions of the jars mentioned in the link

google-api-client **1.10.3-beta**
google-api-services-bigquery **v2-rev19-1.7.2-beta**
google-oauth-client **1.10.1-beta**

The new versions like 1.17 have done away with the constructor:

```
AbstractGoogleJsonClient(HttpTransport,JsonFactory,String,String,HttpRequestInitializer)
```

They use a different implementation now: [AbstractGoogleJsonClient](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient.java?name=1.17)

Comment: I couldnt find a decent download for the google-api-services-bigquery v2-rev19-1.7.2-beta jars, can you help me?

Comment: Use the api-client and oauth-client jars from [here](https://google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/files/google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip) and use the big-query service jars from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-bigquery/v2-rev149-1.17.0-rc/google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev149-1.17.0-rc.jar). These seem to the latest stable versions. In case you get compilation errors just try to fix them as per the new jars. Make sure there is no duplicate jar in your app's library

Comment: I added the jars, and now the code gives this error in the  static void runQueryRpcAndPrint( part :
The method execute() is undefined for the type Bigquery.Jobs.GetQueryResults

Comment: looks like a minor compilation problem. Check the latest java doc [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.GetQueryResults.html)

Comment: In this line :
Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
it collapses (debug mode) and the error is "source not found"